# Fill combobox with csv displaymember

Tags: powershell, csv, combobox, bind

i created a simple windows form with a combobox that i im trying to fill with the full name column in my csv and i want it to return the  abreviated name column value in a variable so i used a hashtable and added both columns, but after selecting an item from the combobox, the $namehash[$return] is null. Shouldnt it return the abreviated name? I found other examples using Combobox.DisplayMember, Combobox.ValueMember,Combobox.DataSource in c# and VB. How can i do this in powershell?

My csv is comma seperated

Name, Shortname

Michigan,MI

Ohio,OH

```
Import-Module Activedirectory


function button ($WF) {

###################Load Assembly for creating form & button######

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)


#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 500;
$form.Height = 190;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;
$form.ControlBox = $True


##############Define text label2

$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 80;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;


############Define text box2 for input

$cBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.combobox”;
$cBox2.Left = 150;
$cBox2.Top = 80;
$cBox2.width = 200;


###############"Add descriptions to combo box"##############
 $NameHash = @{}
import-csv 'C:\temp\test_cidb.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $cBox2.Items.Add($_.Description)
    $NameHash.Add($_.Name,$_.Shortname)
}

############Define text box3 for input

#############Define default values for the input boxes
$defaultValue = “”
$cBox2.Text = $defaultValue;
#############define OK button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 45;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;
$Button.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::BOLD)
############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$cBox2.Text;
$form.Close();};
$button.Add_Click($eventHandler) ;

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($cBox2);
$ret = $form.ShowDialog();

#################return values

return $cbox2.text

}

$return= button “Job Descriptions"
```

I solved my own issue by creating a datatable using that as the data source and binded the combobox using displaymember, valuemember, datasource classes.

```
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($csvfile) 
$line = $reader.ReadLine() 
$columns =  $line.Split($csvdelimiter) 

foreach ($column in $columns) {$null = $datatable.Columns.Add($column) }
   while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  { 
        $row = $datatable.NewRow() 
        $row.itemarray = $line.Split($csvdelimiter) 
        $datatable.Rows.Add($row)   
}
$cbox2.DisplayMember = "Name"
$cbox2.ValueMember = "Shortname"
$cbox2.DataSource = $datatable

$States=cbox2.SelectedValue
```

Comment: what does your csv look like? Can you copy the header and the first line?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have no way of returning what you have added to hash. It will get lost once the function is returned. So, you will need to define that $namehash outside the function first.

```
...
return $cbox2.text
}
$NameHash=@{}
$return= button “Job Descriptions"
```

Then, remove the $NameHash variable that's within the function and use the one from the script:

```
###############"Add descriptions to combo box"##############
##  $NameHash = @{}
import-csv 'C:\temp\a.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $cBox2.Items.Add($_.Description)
    ## $NameHash.Add($_.Name,$_.Shortname)
    $Script:NameHash.Add($_.Name,$_.Shortname)
}
```

Comment: Adil, here is my csv layout below.                             Name, Shortname

Michigan,MI

Ohio,OH

Comment: It's still showing $namehash[<<<<<$return] null. Where is it getting the $return variable. Is that the default property name?

Comment: Thanks for your help. that got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($csvfile) 
$line = $reader.ReadLine() 
$columns =  $line.Split($csvdelimiter) 

foreach ($column in $columns) {$null = $datatable.Columns.Add($column) }
   while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)  { 
        $row = $datatable.NewRow() 
        $row.itemarray = $line.Split($csvdelimiter) 
        $datatable.Rows.Add($row)   
}
$cbox2.DisplayMember = "Name"
$cbox2.ValueMember = "Shortname"
$cbox2.DataSource = $datatable

$States=cbox2.SelectedValue
```