# PowerShell - Get value from combobox, selected value is empty

Tags: powershell

1.csv:

ServerName

Server1

Server2

Server3

I want to import csv file into combobox and get selected value into variable.
I can load above file to combobox, but output variable is null

```
function button ($WF) {

###################Load Assembly for creating form & button######

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)


#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 500;
$form.Height = 190;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;
$form.ControlBox = $True


##############Define text label2

$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 80;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;


############Define text box2 for input

$cBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.combobox”;
$cBox2.Left = 150;
$cBox2.Top = 80;
$cBox2.width = 200;


###############"Add descriptions to combo box"##############
 $NameHash = @{}
import-csv "C:\Users\Komp\Desktop\1.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $cBox2.Items.Add($_.ServerName)
    
}


#############define OK button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 45;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;
$Button.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::BOLD)
############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$cBox2.Text;
$form.Close();};
  
#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($cBox2);
$ret = $form.ShowDialog();

#################return values

$output = $cBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()

}


$return = button “Job Descriptions"
```

The problem is that `$output` variable is empty, how to export selected value into `$output` variable ?

Got this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868750/fill-combobox-with-csv-displaymember) question

Comment: Try `$output = $cBox2.SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817943/powershell-how-do-i-get-information-selected-in-a-combo-box-to-be-used-as-a-var/66818651#66818651) answer your question?

Comment: @Scepticalist ,no tried it already, still empty

Comment: This is an issue with scopes, give my linked answer a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Santiago Squarzon's link, managed to solve it

```
###################Load Assembly for creating form & button######

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)


#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 500;
$form.Height = 190;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;
$form.ControlBox = $True


##############Define text label2

$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 80;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;


############Define text box2 for input

$cBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.combobox”;
$cBox2.Left = 150;
$cBox2.Top = 80;
$cBox2.width = 200;


###############"Add descriptions to combo box"##############
 $NameHash = @{}
import-csv "C:\Users\Komp\Desktop\1.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $cBox2.Items.Add($_.ServerName)
    
}


#############define OK button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 45;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;
$Button.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",12,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::BOLD)
############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$cBox2.Text;
$form.Close();};
$button.Add_Click($eventHandler) ;

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($cBox2);
#$ret = $form.ShowDialog();

#################return values
$button.add_Click({
    #$output =  $cBox2.SelectedItem.Text #Your answer here
    Set-Variable -Name locationResult -Value $combobox1.selectedItem -Force -Scope Script # Use this
    $script:locationResult = $cBox2.selectedItem # or this to retrieve the user selection
})

$form.Controls.Add($button)
$form.Controls.Add($cBox2)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: You're using both methods to retrieve the `comboBox` selection, use only one, I added both for anyone to decide which one to use :P. Its either `Set-Variable` or `$script:Var`

Comment: I would also combine the code into just the one `$button.Add_Click(..)` event handler.